# Android how to let users interact with each other

Tags: java, android, facebook

Been doing basic Android development for awhile now. Ready to implement some ideas previously I was to unsure to touch on.

If this question has already been asked please feel free to direct me there as I can not find a thread.

Lets say based on user interaction some data is collected and entered to either a text or XML file. How can I enable this user to send this data thats been collected to another Android user using the same app? Are there any APIs out there capable of transferring data between users?

In a simple example, Facebook Messaging. One message is created by a user and sent to another user. How can I get on the right path to this?

Thank you!

Comment: You need sockets as well as a server for both users to interact. This topic is pretty big for one post. Please refer to Java sockets. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/